# How to place a view below other just animated?

Tags: android, animation, view

i started learning animation on android today, and i'm having trouble positioning views after animations end.

When app starts, It shows an search EditText in the center of the screen, and when you search for something, this EditText should slide to top using this code below

```
public void slideToTop(View view){
    view.animate()
            .translationY((-parent.getHeight()/2) + view.getHeight())
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(500)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                                layoutContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                             }
                         });
                    fadeOutAndHideImage(logo);
}
```

How can I show the results below the EditText that now is on top of the layout?
    I tried to use layout_below attribute from RelativeLayout, the set the visibility when the animation ends, but it seems that the position is calculated before the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set position of your view `programatically` to `(-parent.getHeight()/2) + view.getHeight()` using `Layout Params` when the animation ends, this might help you to solve your problem.